SELECT with COUNT(*) to return an integer to a variable
I am trying to run a SELECT to count some items into a table into GCP BigQuery to get the amount of items that have a "failed" status for a specific row.
I am using bq query for that and my command looks like this:
bq query \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
'
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  `myproject.mydataset.mytable` CROSS JOIN UNNEST(controls) AS c
WHERE
  profile LIKE "%/myprofile/%"
AND
  vm = "myvm"
AND
  c.status = "failed"
'

I want to assign the results to a variable on a shell script, so I run this:
MYVAR=$(bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable` CROSS JOIN UNNEST(controls) AS c WHERE profile LIKE "%/myprofile/%" AND vm = "myvm" AND c.status = "failed"')

But when I echo $MYVAR I got a table like this:
echo $MYVAR
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|   6 |
+-----+

I wanted the result to be an integer, like:
echo $MYVAR
6

How can I make the SQL SELECT return just an integer? Or how can I filter the result table and get only the result field?
Thank you

The deafult output of the bq command is supposed to be human readable.  If we look at the documentation for the bq command we see a flag called --format that allows us to control the output.  There are two values that may be of use to us ... these are:

json
csv

One outputs as a JSON document and the other as CSV data.  Since the output of a query is a table, you should realize that a scalar value is a special case.
My recommendation ... look at the output of running:
MYVAR=$(bq query --format=json --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable` CROSS JOIN UNNEST(controls) AS c WHERE profile LIKE "%/myprofile/%" AND vm = "myvm" AND c.status = "failed"')

You will likely find that the output is now a JSON string.  From there, you should be prepared to parse/extract from the JSON.  It looks like you may be writing Liunx shell script.  Consider looking at the jq command line tool for JSON processing.

It worked, had to add the following | jq -r '.[].f0_' at the end of the command. Thanks
